# PHP how to create WDDX XML file and read WDDX XML file to object?

Tags: php, xml, wddx

```
create xml
$country="Australia";
$va=wddx_serialize_value($country);
$data="data.xml";
$fp=fopen($data, "w+") or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fp, $va, strlen($va));
fclose($fp);
```

how can I get back the value "Australia" by read the xml file? Thanks

Comment: Use `wddx_deserialize`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wddx-deserialize.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$va = file_get_contents("data.xml");
$country = wddx_deserialize($va);
```